# How can i search for a string from one column in a dataframe in a string value in another column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, nlp, contains

[image]
I want to search 'search_value' in 'Search in string' column for every row and return TRUE if any of the words separated by | in search_value are present in 'Search in string'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the actual data, not a picture of it.

Comment: Please post the data as is and not a picture so I can easily copy-paste it and test the example.

Answer (score 1):

You could make good use of the keyword `any` and use `apply(lambda x:)` to your dataframe. It would result in this:

```
df['Flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: True if any(i in x['Search in string'].split() for i in x['Search_value'].split('|')) else False,axis=1)
```

This results in the expected output:

```
                                        search_value  ...  Flag
0  civic|men|boy|furnishing|clothing|non durable|...  ...  True
1  environmental|cosmetic|beauty|perfume|apparel|...  ...  True
```